# use returned Object from method in inline-if

Tags: arrays, typescript, if-statement, inline, shift

I was using [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and started wondering if you could use it in an inline-if as it returns an `object` or `undefined`.

For example to consume an array element by element:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

const handleData = (n: number) => {
  console.log(n);
}

while (true) {
  const n = array.shift();
  if (n) {
    handleData(n);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

But would it also be possible to use it in an inline-if?

```
while (true) {
  handleData(array.shift() ? /** use object **/ : /** do nothing **/);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(array.shift() || 0)`

Comment: it depends what you're trying to accomplish. Your array might contain falsy elements - like the number `0` - and then `array.shift() || 0` will return 0 without signalling that the array is empty.

Comment: Oh I see maybe I should change the question... Can I just return the elements and when there are none I return?

Comment: which object are you talking about?

Comment: like `Person = {name: string, age: number}` it's more a general question

Comment: By "inline-if" you mean the conditional/ternary operator `?:`? Because anything that can be used in an if condition can be used as the condition for a conditional operator.

Comment: Why does the OP just not try?

Comment: Since it's TypeScript, just use `handleData(n!)`

Comment: I didn't know about that @HereticMonkey, that answers my question

Comment: anything wrong with `array.forEach(handleData)` ?

Comment: I wanted to also remove the item thats why I used `shift()`

Comment: @Tim4497 ... Of cause one could do ... `const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]; let item; while (item = array.shift()) { handleData(item); };` ... but then 1) one has to assure that no falsy value is part of the array; 2) a lot of developers and linters will complain about the assignment within the while clause.

Comment: @PeterSeliger That's a good solution as well for my case, so thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

Just check the length of the array.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

while (array.length) console.log(array.shift());
```

Comment: I changed my example so that typescript would throw an error because `handleData()` would only except a `number` and not `undefined`.

Comment: @Tim4497 ... with Nina's example code one does not run into a `undefined` value being passed to `handleData` as long as such a value is not an array item itself. With the last valid shift one passes the last array item, then array's length will be zero which does prevent any further while iteration steps.

Comment: @Tim4497 The code in this answer does not produce errors in TypeScript. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAnjAvDA2gRgDQwBMBAzAQCwECsBAbAQOwEAcAugNwCwAUDwO4ALAJYAbAKYwAFImQoAdOLABzKAICUMUJBDiFIJdKSo5EYQDMoktWvZA

Comment: I talked about my example not Ninas, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Tim4497 it's not my data. what do you like to achieve?

Comment: Its already solved, but thanks!